# using input type file with angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I use angular material 2 FAB buttons to open a browse input dialog? This can be done in HTML by this way.

```html
<button type="button">
    <label for="file-input">click</label>
</button>
<input type="file" id="file-input" style="display:none">
```

I tried following the same approach with material 2, but it doesn't work.

```html
<button md-mini-fab type="button">
    <label for="fileToUpload">
        <md-icon>add</md-icon>
    </label>
</button>
<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" style="display:none;">
```

Are there any other ways that will work? Thank you.

Comment: You can use a button and an input / a label and an input.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763240/5042169

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```html
<button (click)="fileInput.click()">
  <md-icon>library_add</md-icon>
  <span>Select</span>
  <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onFileInput($event)" style="display:none;" />
</button>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as it does not break abstraction. Angular is meant to be used w/o any knowledge of the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, very simple and useful solution. This is the correct answer for me.

Comment: if I do this, `onFileInput` fires only once?

Comment: how do I access #fileInput by dynamic id

Comment: this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = null; you need to reset the value to null to multiple firing.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644841/angular-6-viewchild-access-value-of-nativeelement-span-class

Answer (score 16):

You need to simply trigger the `click` for your file input.

```
<button md-mini-fab type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click()">
  <label for="fileToUpload"><md-icon>add</md-icon></label>
</button>
<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: this will even strip down the need for label tag, but this solution uses JS.

I actually wanted to use as minimum JS as possible. Specifically I don't want to use any thing like document.getElementById and similar things. Well it may save me if nothing else works.

Comment: @saifullah: you may go for a directive then and can achieve it by ` `element.bind("click",.`, but it will be like making it more complex. :),

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143052/how-to-manually-set-focus-on-mat-form-field-in-angular-6 @anoop

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
<input #file type="file" [hidden]="true" accept="image/*" (change)="upload(file.files)">
<button mat-button #upload (click)="file.click()">Upload file</button>
```

`<mat-button>` is from https://material.angular.io

We are hiding the basic input button and linking the material button to the file upload.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about your cases, but in my Angular5 application I used this HTML structure for uploading files on server:

```
<label for="uploadPicture" class="upload-file">
   <mat-icon>add_a_photo</mat-icon>
</label>
<input type="file"
       id="uploadPicture"
       class="hidden-input"
       accept="image/jpeg, .jpeg, image/png, .png, image/pjpeg, .jpg"
       (change)="selectFile($event.target.files[0])">
```

In my case this solution working great. No need to trigger `click` event, because when you click on `<label>` that related to `input` it's same as `click` on `input`.

Comment: wow, thats so awesome, I was looking for the same. But how did you displayed the selected filename???

Comment: @Jaydeep Simple solution - (change)="selectFile($event.target.files)" will pass filedata in function argument. In you .ts file You will have:
public selectFile(file): void { this.someVariableForFileName = file.name }
and show this variable in HTML view:
<div class="file-name" *ngIf="someVariableForFileName">{{someVariableForFileName}}</div>
Hope, it help You. :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be a combination of md-button, md-dialog, and md-input. The mini fab button must have a click event to trigger the md-dialog component.

```
<button md-mini-fab type="button" (click)="openDialog()">
    <label for="fileToUpload">
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
    </label>
</button>
```

Within the md-dialog component, the md-input field can be added.

```
<h1 md-dialog-title>Dialog</h1>
<div md-dialog-actions>
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput id="fileToUpload" type="file">
  </md-input-container>
  <p>
    <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Option 1')">Option 1</button>
    <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Option 2')">Option 2</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Please see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SgXke45dWiL7jhObtGvQ) example to get all/specific details.

Comment: that's actually two clicks for just one input type file functionality, which isn't what I asked for. I want to just give material 2 design to input having type file. Which isn't any option provided by material by now. There are only workarounds available for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button and an input. Make sure that **button doesn't enclose input**.

```
<button (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload</button>
<input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onFileInput($event)" multiple style="display:none;" />
```

You can also use a label enclosing an input.

```
<label>
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    <input type="file" (change)="onFileInput($event)" multiple />
</label>
```