# Angular 6 - @ViewChild Access value of nativeElement span class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using @ViewChild is Angular.

On my **app.component.html** I have:

```
<div #somename>Mark<span class="somethingelse">Hello something else</span></div>
```

And on my **app.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('somename') SomeName;

  constructor() {}

  getInputValue() {
 alert(this.SomeName.nativeElement('span').getElementByClassName('somethingelse').innerHTML);
  }
```

This is not returning anything.

My question is how to I target the span's class and get it's value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your view child should be:

```
@ViewChild("somename") somename: ElementRef;
```

Then you can do:

```
this.somename.nativeElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML
```

Comment: That's returning the class name I need in innerHTML inside that span

Comment: No it doesn't. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbjbdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>Mark<span class="somethingelse" #somename>Hello something else</span></div>

@ViewChild('somename') mySpan: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.mySpan.nativeElement.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: That's returning the class name I need in innerHTML inside that span

Comment: Misunderstanding I guess. Replace className with innerHTML